# What is best practice creating Jmeter script from java code or from Jmeter UI

Tags: java, jmeter

what might be the difference/advantage of creating Jmeter script from java code over doing the same from Jmeter UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference, in both cases you have either .jmx script (which is basically an [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp) file) or a [HashTree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) representing your test plan which will be passed to [JMeter Engine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/JMeterEngine.html) for execution

However be aware that creating JMeter tests using GUI is only supported and recommended way, if you go for other approaches the chance you will get support in case of problems will be much lower.

Moreover, creating a test in Java using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) is not trivial and most probably you will have to open JMeter GUI and load your generated test plan for debugging purposes very often.

An easier option of programmatic creation of JMeter test is using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool. Taurus is free and open source automation framework which supports JMeter, Selenium, Gatling, Locust, Postman and many more tools. It also provides possibility to [create a JMeter test using simple declarative YAML](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207387369-Creating-a-Taurus-Test) syntax.